# PHP MySql Database Array update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to update one row in my database like this.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$sizes = array($_POST['size_king'], 
               $_POST['size_queen'],
               $_POST['size_double']
              );

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE beds 
                SET `Available Sizes` = '$sizes' 
                WHERE ID = '$prod_id' " 
            );
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

I want this data to only update one row, and the data must be separated by a comma.

I am thinking maybe a FOR loop, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function .

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$sizes = array($_POST['size_king'], 
               $_POST['size_queen'],
               $_POST['size_double']
              );
$sizes=implode(",",$sizes);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE beds 
                SET `Available Sizes` = '$sizes' 
                WHERE ID = '$prod_id' " 
            );
}
```

Comment: Implode is a good solution as long as he/she wants add CSV values in database.

Comment: @RajivPingale what we code just depends upon requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `implode` function will serve your purpose.

implode joins array elements into a string separated by the glue we specify. The syntax is:

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

Refer to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Example:

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

// Empty string when using an empty array:
var_dump(implode('hello', array())); // string(0) ""

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a catch when you create database never name your table as "Available Beds" i mean don't use space try using "AvailabaleSizes" or Available_Sizes or "availableSizes" after this change write your query like below.

```
($con, "UPDATE `beds`   SET Available_Sizes = '$sizes' WHERE ID = '$prod_id'");
```